# TeamCity Code Coverage of C++ code

Tags: unit-testing, teamcity, code-coverage, dotcover

We have a project using C#, C++/Cli and some native C++ code. We use TeamCity for building and testing.

We run the tests using vstest.console (VS2012 test runner).

For managed code, dotCover (which is integrated into TeamCity) is used for code coverage. However, it doesn't work with native C++ code (which is to be expected).

How do I get code coverage results our unit tests for the native C++ parts into TeamCity? Ideally, the solution would be free.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We use [Bullseye Coverage](http://www.bullseye.com/) for C++ code coverage. We then use the provided `covxml` tool to convert the binary coverage files into an XML file, which we then read out a bunch of useful attributes for function and conditional coverage (e.g. `fn_total`, `fn_cov`, `cd_total`, `cd_cov`) and provide these to TeamCity via the [statistics service messages](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD7/Build+Script+Interaction+with+TeamCity#BuildScriptInteractionwithTeamCity-ReportingBuildStatistics) using the [predefined coverage keys](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD7/Custom+Chart#CustomChart-predefinedStatisticsKeys).

It was a bit of work to set up, but I think TeamCity still has no support for any C++ coverage tool, so our solution still works well for us years later.

**Edit:** I've uploaded the XML [parsing code](https://gist.github.com/jonorossi/8333504) for our in-house tool to a Gist.

Comment: It would be great if you could share your xml parsing scripts :)

Comment: Sure, there is nothing secret about it. I uploaded it to a gist, see the post above. I don't think we are using the latest Bullseye (however definitely newer than the comments in the code) so YMMV, but if I recall correctly this file format was published by the authors so it shouldn't be broken.

Comment: Here is the documentation on the Bullseye web site: http://www.bullseye.com/help/ref-covxml.html

Comment: This is great, thanks for sharing. Your code references a ReportHelper class, which is missing. Anyway, it'd be enough for me if you'd told me which teamcity coverage keys did you map to which bullseye result attributes. Thanks!

Comment: @iwo Sorry about that, I've added ReportHelper.cs to the Gist. I've also added OutputTeamCityServiceMessages.cs, it just has the method that outputs the TeamCity service messages to stdout. IIRC the bottom two are set to 100 otherwise the TeamCity web UI used to break, but that might no longer be needed. 'B' is meant to be for block coverage, so I just used it for branches anyway.